# update and insert query for split name

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

can anyone please help me right the following stored procedure of split name in first and last name in stored procedure in SQL for update and insert query.

```
Create[dbo].[storedprocedure] 
SELECT LEFT(@FullName, CHARINDEX(',', @FullName) - 1) AS [FirstName],
       RIGHT(@FullName, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@FullName)) - 1) AS [LastName] 
From table name
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This will not compile, where is `@FullName` defined?

Comment: That is parameter passed for fullName

Comment: I know what *it's supposed to do*, but it's not in your code above... Also you're not selecting any columns from the `table` or using the `name` alias anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your request you could create a type to use as list parameter for the procedure

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[FullNamesList] AS TABLE(
    [FullName] varchar(20) NULL
);
```

and after this, you can create this procedure to insert splitter name the table you prefer (my FirstLastNameTable)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[storedprocedure]
    @groupFullNames FullNamesList READONLY
    
    AS
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO FirstLastNameTable(FirstName, LastName)
        SELECT LEFT(G.FullName, CHARINDEX(',', G.FullName) - 1) AS [FirstName],
               RIGHT(G.FullName, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(G.FullName)) - 1) AS [LastName]
        FROM @groupFullNames G

    END
```